# Error when running install pyhon3-dev in docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a Python docker container, when I run the command "docker-compose up" to build the Dockerfile it throws me this error message below
Trying to build the image produces the following error:

```
0 16.66 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#0 16.69 Fetched 35.2 MB in 9s (3993 kB/s)
#0 16.71 Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.11-minimal:amd64.
(Reading database ... 6705 files and directories currently installed.)
#0 16.71 Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.11-minimal_3.11.2-6_amd64.deb ...
#0 16.71 Unpacking libpython3.11-minimal:amd64 (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 16.78 Selecting previously unselected package python3.11-minimal.
#0 16.78 Preparing to unpack .../python3.11-minimal_3.11.2-6_amd64.deb ...
#0 16.78 Unpacking python3.11-minimal (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 16.92 Setting up libpython3.11-minimal:amd64 (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 16.93 Setting up python3.11-minimal (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 17.01 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-311.pyc.140584693250096'dpkg: error processing package python3.11-minimal (--configure):
#0 17.02  installed python3.11-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#0 17.02 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 17.02  python3.11-minimal
#0 17.04 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-dev]: exit code: 100
```

My requirements.txt file looks like:

```
amqp==5.1.1
asgiref==3.7.2
asttokens==2.4.0
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
billiard==4.1.0
bs4==0.0.1
celery==5.3.1
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
click==8.1.7
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.3.0
comm==0.1.4
cron-descriptor==1.4.0
debugpy==1.6.7
decorator==5.1.1
Django==4.2.3
django-celery-beat==2.5.0
django-celery-results==2.5.1
django-redis==5.3.0
django-timezone-field==6.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
exceptiongroup==1.1.3
executing==1.2.0
flower==2.0.1
h11==0.14.0
humanize==4.8.0
idna==3.4
ipykernel==6.25.2
ipython==8.15.0
jedi==0.19.0
jupyter_client==8.3.1
jupyter_core==5.3.1
kombu==5.3.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
nest-asyncio==1.5.7
outcome==1.2.0
packaging==23.1
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
platformdirs==3.10.0
prometheus-client==0.17.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.39
psutil==5.9.5
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
Pygments==2.16.1
PySocks==1.7.1
python-crontab==3.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
pyzmq==25.1.1
redis==5.0.0
requests==2.31.0
selenium==4.12.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.4.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
stack-data==0.6.2
tornado==6.3.3
traitlets==5.9.0
trio==0.22.2
trio-websocket==0.10.3
typing_extensions==4.7.1
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.4
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.6
wsproto==1.2.0
```

I'm using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV pythondontwritebytecode 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-dev \
                                         gcc \
                                         libc-dev \
                                        libffi-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput && \
    python3 manage.py migrate --noinput && \
    python3 manage.py loaddata data.json
```

When I build Docker Compos, it gives this error and does not install the requirements
how can i fix this ?

Comment: To debug this kind of thing its quite possible to simply `docker run -it python:3.9-slim` and then step through the commands in the Dockerfile. Any problems you have running them interactively you can fix and patch in the Dockerfile.